# Why does PySequence_GetItem return a new reference?

Tags: cpython

I've been caught out by a memory leak in a C/C++ python extension for assuming that `PySequence_GetItem` would return a borrowed reference, in the same way as `PyList_GetItem` and `PyTuple_GetItem`. My question is: why does `PySequence_GetItem` return a new reference while `PyList_GetItem` and `PyTuple_GetItem` return borrowed references?

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_GetItem):

```
PyObject* PySequence_GetItem(PyObject *o, Py_ssize_t i)
    Return value: New reference.
    Return the ith element of o, or NULL on failure. This is the equivalent of the Python expression o[i].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the new reference from `PySequence`, because this is what the `PySequence`-protocol defines.

There are however good reasons, to define the protocol this way: not all sequencies are backed by memory (like `list`, `tuple`), for some the items are created on the fly (like `range`, `unicode`).

For `list` and `tuple` all items are owned by the `list`/`tuple` (they aren't temporary objects) so we can borrow them (the borrowing is a small optimization) - the `list`/`tuple` will free the memory in the end.

`range` is another example for a sequence. It implements [PySequence-protocol](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/rangeobject.c#L561-L570)):

```c
static PySequenceMethods range_as_sequence = {
    (lenfunc)range_length,      /* sq_length */
    0,                          /* sq_concat */
    0,                          /* sq_repeat */
    (ssizeargfunc)range_item,   /* sq_item */
    0,                          /* sq_slice */
    0,                          /* sq_ass_item */
    0,                          /* sq_ass_slice */
    (objobjproc)range_contains, /* sq_contains */
};
```

However, the objects returned by `PySequence_GetItem` are temporaries (i.e. nobody owns a reference to it outside of the function), we can verify this in the source code of [`range_item`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/rangeobject.c#L285-L295):

```c
static PyObject *
range_item(rangeobject *r, Py_ssize_t i)
{
    PyObject *res, *arg = PyLong_FromSsize_t(i);
    if (!arg) {
        return NULL;
    }
    res = compute_range_item(r, arg);
    Py_DECREF(arg);
    return res;
}
```

where `compute_range_item` boils down to [`compute_item`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/rangeobject.c#L218):

```c
static PyObject *
compute_item(rangeobject *r, PyObject *i)
{
    PyObject *incr, *result;
    /* PyLong equivalent to:
     *    return r->start + (i * r->step)
     */
    incr = PyNumber_Multiply(i, r->step);
    if (!incr)
        return NULL;
    result = PyNumber_Add(r->start, incr);
    Py_DECREF(incr);
    return result;
}
```

Nobody owns the object in returned `result`, thus the receiver has to take care for decreasing the reference count.

There are maybe other solutions possible (some kind of caching of created items), but returning a new reference is the most simple/transparent way to handle the problem of items created on the fly.